# Set child element height to 100 percent of parent element

Tags: html, css, frontend

http://jsfiddle.net/BZNUr/

```
#container {
background:red;
padding:10px;
height:100%;
}

.button {
color: white;
width:200px;
background:blue;
margin:2px;
display:inline-block;
height:100%;
vertical-align:top;
}

<div id="container">
<div class="button">text text text text text text text text</div>
<div class="button">what</div>
</div>
```

How do I set the second child element to take a 100% height of the container element? I would like to avoid specifying the height of container as well as absolute positioning. Is there a simple way to do this? (Side note: Why do I have to post code if all my code is provided in the jsfiddle link? This is just messy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use display:table / table-cell ( http://jsfiddle.net/BZNUr/14/ ) :

```
#container {
    display:table;
}
.button {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

That will change some of the other visual aspects, but you could compensate by changing other CSS properties (I didn't do this because I wasn't sure if it was important to you).

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. It's oddly beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

did you try it on outside jsfiddle,i mean place it in an html file and open in a browser,
your code works perfectly in my Browsers(chrome and Firefox) even when specifying the 100% width to the parent container.